# How to create a nested list from 2 other lists based on the range of the values?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following two lists:

```
list1 = ["valueX", "valueY", "valueZ"]
list2 = [2, 0, 4]
```

I'm trying to get the following output:

```
desirablelist = [["valueX0", "valueX1", "valueX2"], ["valueY0"], ["valueZ0", "valueZ1", "valueZ2", "valueZ3", "valueZ4"]]
```

I tried something like the following, but it is not working as expected:

```
arg_list = []
final_arg_list = []
for x,k in zip(list1,list2):
 for z in range(x):
    arg_list.append( k + str(z) )
 final_arg_list.append(arg_list)
```

I am instead getting the following output:

```
[['valueX0', 'valueX1', 'valueZ0', 'valueZ1', 'valueZ2', 'valueZ3'], ['valueX0', 'valueX1', 'valueZ0', 'valueZ1', 'valueZ2', 'valueZ3'], ['valueX0', 'valueX1', 'valueZ0', 'valueZ1', 'valueZ2', 'valueZ3']]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do the numbers in list2 mean? Length of new sub-list? Index of last item in new sub-list? Neither of those possibilities seems to match the example.

Comment: Why is there no `"valueY0"` in the second inner list?

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: according to your example, seems like you got it the other way around. It should be `for k,x in zip(list1, list2)` and you should put the `arg_list` initialization **inside** the outer loop

Comment: The output i get is: [['valueX0', 'valueX1', 'valueZ0', 'valueZ1', 'valueZ2', 'valueZ3'], ['valueX0', 'valueX1', 'valueZ0', 'valueZ1', 'valueZ2', 'valueZ3'], ['valueX0', 'valueX1', 'valueZ0', 'valueZ1', 'valueZ2', 'valueZ3']]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are getting the output provided in your question, since the code you have currently returns an error (which you can see by running it here: https://repl.it/repls/HumbleRuralSales). Based on your `desirablelist` example though, here are a few changes you need to make to your code to get the desired results:

1. `arg_list = []` needs to be defined inside the first loop so that it resets for each list1 value. If you define it outside of the loop, all the values will just be appended to each other and the list will never reset:

   ```
   [
       ["valueX0", "valueX1", "valueX2", "valueY0", "valueZ0", "valueZ1", "valueZ2", "valueZ3", "valueZ4"],
       ["valueX0", "valueX1", "valueX2", "valueY0", "valueZ0", "valueZ1", "valueZ2", "valueZ3", "valueZ4"],
       ["valueX0", "valueX1", "valueX2", "valueY0", "valueZ0", "valueZ1", "valueZ2", "valueZ3", "valueZ4"]
   ]
   ```

   By setting `arg_list` back to an empty array inside the loop (`= []`), you basically "clear" the array after each iteration of a list1 value and you will get the proper result:

   ```
   [
       ["valueX0", "valueX1", "valueX2"],
       ["valueY0"],
       ["valueZ0", "valueZ1", "valueZ2", "valueZ3", "valueZ4"]
   ]
   ```
2. In the second loop, you need to swap the `x` and `k` variables. Right now, the second loop is trying to loop through a range of the list1 values. list1's "valueX", "valueY", "valueZ" are strings and not numbers, so they do not have a range and your code therefore returns the following error:

   > TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

   You want to instead loop through the range of the integer values of list2.
3. In your `desirablelist` example, each list1 set contains values for one more than the value in list2. You therefore need to change the range of the second loop from `k` to `k + 1`.

Final code:

```
list1 = ["valueX", "valueY", "valueZ"]
list2 = [2, 0, 4]

final_arg_list = []
for x,k in zip(list1,list2):
    arg_list = []
    for z in range(k + 1):
        arg_list.append(x + str(z))
    final_arg_list.append(arg_list)

print(final_arg_list)
```

Working fiddle: [repl.it/repls/CautiousJubilantOperatingenvironment#main.py](http://repl.it/repls/CautiousJubilantOperatingenvironment#main.py)